# Запись ключа RSA в файл

Tags: java, android

Генерирую ключи шифрования RSA и пишу их в файл таким образом:

```
try {
                    final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                    keyGen.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());
                    final KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

                    File privateKeyFile = new File(md5(nickname.getText().toString()) + "_private_key");
                    File publicKeyFile = new File(md5(nickname.getText().toString()) + "_public_key");

                    if (privateKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
                        privateKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    }
                    privateKeyFile.createNewFile();

                    if (publicKeyFile.getParentFile() != null) {
                        publicKeyFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    }
                    publicKeyFile.createNewFile();

                    BufferedWriter pubOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFile)));
                    pubOut.write(byte2Hex(key.getPublic().getEncoded()));
                    pubOut.flush();
                    pubOut.close();

                    BufferedWriter privOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFile)));
                    privOut.write(byte2Hex(key.getPrivate().getEncoded()));
                    privOut.flush();
                    privOut.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Программа перескакивает на Exception  на этой строке:

```
privateKeyFile.createNewFile();
```

Что я упустил и делаю не так? Пытаюсь сделать так как указано в [этом](http://findevelop.blogspot.ru/2013/04/java.html) примере

Ошибка:

```
08-03 15:30:51.468 1869-1924/com.example.jack.myapplication E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe980a400
08-03 15:35:29.259 2653-6152/com.example.jack.myapplication E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe9807140
08-03 15:35:32.029 2653-2653/com.example.jack.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jack.myapplication, PID: 2653
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4452)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
  at com.example.jack.myapplication.register.onClick_register(register.java:188)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4447) 
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

Comment: Забыл добавить сообщение  об ошибке, теперь добавил

Comment: что в строчке "register.java:188"?